# change color of bold tag inside link

Tags: html, css

For one reason or another we have to keep the markup this way, I'm simply trying to change the color of the bold tag on the hover of the href.  I could write some jquery bu I THINK this is possible with simple css. Blanking though, Any help would be much appreciated, i've tried different variants and can't nail it!.

```
<a href="http://yolocal.dev:3000/catalog_items/3080191" class="deal_percent_link_style"><b span="deal_data_wrapper">-73% </b></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with CSS:

```
a.deal_percent_link_style:hover b {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add some CSS:

```
a.deal_percent_link_style:hover {
    color: red;
}​
```